# CreateML make stateIn optional

Tags: createml

I'm trying to train a model on CreateML for activity classification from motion data. CreateML has produced a trained LSTM, which I would like to integrate into my app.

However, in the app, the `stateIn` field is non-optional, and I am not sure what to pass it to get my predictions. How should I proceed?

Thank you!